# How to hide Relationship Lines in 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

You used to be able to hide the dotted lines of a Parent Relationship by going to the Display tab and disabling the checkbox of "Relationship Lines". That option cannot be found there anymore. Where is it now?

Answer (score 10):

In 2.80 all things that displays on top of the renderable objects calls **overlays**. You can edit what do you want to display in viewport in this **Overlays** popover:

[image]

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to specify by-relationship, to only knock out a few that are getting in the way but leave others?

Comment: Only if you make it using regular objects

Answer (score 1):

3D view HUD->Overlays->Objects->Relationship Lines

Answer (score 1):

And to do this in python:

```
bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_relationship_lines = False
```